# How do I pause a JFrame while another is running

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, wait

I'm making a Server with a database inside, but while I'm loading the main JFrame and while I'm connecting to the database reading username & password from a .properties file I chosed to let the user know that the program is running, what the program is doing in that specific moment, and also let him create a .properties file if it not exists (first launch).
The problem is that I need to create 2 jframes, 1 that shows the launch progress, and 1 that appears only when user needs to create a .properties file: the problem is that I have to pause the first one while the second is running, and restart running the first while the second is closed performing all actions; I made it in two ways, but it didn't work: first, I tried inserting a wait() call opening the second JFrame and a notify() call while closing it; second, I tried using threads, but the problem is that the thread that I stop doesn't start when it should... here's some code:

```
jFrame1.setBounds(0,0,500,500);
    this.setVisible(true);
    jProgressBar2.setValue(0);
    prop = new Properties();
    jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText()+"Searching file config.properties... \n");
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("config.properties");
        jProgressBar2.setValue(33);
        jLabel3.setText("33");
        jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText()+"File config.properties found... \n");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        jFrame1.setVisible(true);
        jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText()+"File config.properties not found... \n");
    }
```

I want to pause while I ented the "catch" section; "this" is the first JFrame, "jFrame1" is the second one.
Some hints/tips?

Comment: See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution: don't use multiple JFrames. Make the window that's acting as a modal dialog not a second JFrame, but rather a real modal JDialog.

We should probably close this question as a duplicate as this exact same question gets asked again and again.

Comment: I know a lot of people asks for this thing, but the problem is that the answers I found doesn't work: using common methods as threads or wait it doesn't work. I'll look for JDialog, but I'd rather prefer 2 different JFrames for internal management.

Comment: @user2346235: I'm confused. What is your objection towards use of a JDialog? What do you mean by "internal management"?

Comment: Easiest way is just to pass some content pane in `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, contentPaneName,"Title here",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);` and voila! It must work!

Comment: @brano88: that could work, but don't make the first parameter null; rather it should be the root JFrame, the one that must be paused.

Comment: My excuses. I didn't know JDialog; just looked for em in the documentation, and I found out that they can be a valid solution.

Comment: @user2346235: good deal. Actually they are more than **a** valid solution; they are ***the*** valid solution. Best of luck with them!