# How to make a program to sleep until my Thread ends?

Tags: java, swing

Inside a JFrame class, I start one Thread. That thread checks something and return a boolean as true or false. Inside the JFrame class I want to check that boolean, and do actions according to the results of the thread.
Now my question is how can I make my JFrame to wait untill the Thread ends?

How to make a program to sleep until my Thread ends ? I dont wanna to use Thread.join(). Is it possible?

---

I am interacting with the user in another window.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague -- what exactly do you mean by "thread checks something ...."? -- Are you interacting with the user in another window? If so, use a modal dialog. Are you running a background thread such as with a SwingWorker? If so, then use a PropertyChangeListener added to the SwingWorker and activate your GUI on completion. Please tell the details and show the pertinent code. Please improve your question.

Comment: I am interacting with the user in another window.

Comment: Then that "other window" should be a modal dialog. Please check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367968/how-do-i-pause-a-jframe-while-another-is-running) for more on this, as well as [these questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+pause+a+jframe+another+jframe) for a **lot** more on this.

Comment: If you need more specific help, then still improve this question. Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the second window a modal dialog such as either a JOptionPane or a modal JDialog. Either one will freeze the calling window until the dialog window is no longer visible. Please check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367968/how-do-i-pause-a-jframe-while-another-is-running) for more on this, as well as [these questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+pause+a+jframe+another+jframe) for a **lot** more on this.